# How to split a large point vector layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, big-data

I need to split my shapefiles into much smaller pieces so that I can upload them onto the Postgis server. Shapefiles have DBF files with 14 Go (1,000,000 rows) and I need them to be under 2 Go.

I've tried selecting 100,000 rows to then try and save the selected features as a different file but QGIS just instantly freezes.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How did you manage to generate a DBF of that size, I didn't think that was  possible?

Comment: it was generated from a CSV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of playing with workarounds try if GDAL can do the job for you directly. If command

```
ogrinfo -al -so your_big_shapefile.shp
```

seems successful you have good chance to have luck with ogr2ogr as well. Read 
http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html and http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html and try

```
ogr2ogr -f PG PG:"dbname='databasename' host='addr' port='5432' user='x' password='y'" your_big_shapefile.shp
```

Comment: Your first line returns an error saying it can't load requested dll. Second one returned "unable to load datasource"

Comment: Dll error means that there is something wrong with your GDAL installation.

Comment: I'm getting this error http://i.imgur.com/0cNXHGL.jpg

Comment: It seems that the file name gets truncated at the space character in your path `C:\users\Pedro Santos\...` I am not sure how to make your FOR command to work with spaces. Myself I would not even try but use a path without spaces.

Comment: I'm trying to go more simple now and got this error http://i.imgur.com/ePJjZOh.jpg

Comment: The error may mean that GDAL does can't interpret the native projection of your shapefile and it tries to insert some dummy projection into PostGIS. Or then it finds a projection but PostGIS is missing just that projection. Your user name does not have rights to do inserts into spatial_ref_system which leads to an error. Find out the EPSG  code of your source data and add the -a_srs parameter into your ogr2ogr command like `-a_srs epsg:4326`.

Comment: It uploaded 75% of the features in just 2 minutes but still got a weird error saying the table already exists, gonna try again

Comment: Before new trial drop the table or run ogr2ogr with -overwrite.

Comment: I got this error now using the overwrite http://i.imgur.com/CNiyI7k.jpg

Comment: So drop the index with pgAdmin. I would have thought that -overwrite takes care of dropping the index as well but for some reason it did not happen for you.

Comment: OMG it worked!! You sir are a genius and may very well have saved the future of broadband in the UK

Comment: hey I was trying to import some more stuff and now I got this error. http://i.imgur.com/rIuVUHm.png How do I get around this error? thanks

Comment: Add `-nlt promote_to_multi`into the ogr2ogr command. Documented in http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html: Starting with GDAL 1.10, PROMOTE_TO_MULTI can be used to automatically promote layers that mix polygon or multipolygons to multipolygons, and layers that mix linestrings or multilinestrings to multilinestrings. Can be useful when converting shapefiles to PostGIS and other target drivers that implement strict checks for geometry types.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid loading the shapefile in QGIS first - use the `import layer/file` button in the DB Manager dialog.

[image]

Select the **file**, not a loaded layer, with the button to the right of the Input box. You'll need to specify CRS and have the option to reproject in the same step:

[image]

Tested this with 200,000 features - ~ 1 minute to import.

Comment: Not sure if you have a super futuristic computer with NASA level internet connection but for me even without the layer being loaded it only imported 1,400 features out of the 1 million in one minute

Comment: Can you successfully load into PostGIS a small subset (say, 1,000 records) of the shapefile to begin with?

Comment: you can allways use shp2psql   http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg . For speed remove indexes on insert recreate them after you have imported data

Comment: @Simbamangu The small shapefile I have with only 150Mb loaded fine, the problem are all the other ones with >10Gb